# Designer fails to load in visual studio, GenericArguments[0] violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, infragistics, windows-forms-designer

I have a GUI containing several infragistics elements which when I load them give me the error

```
GenericArguments[0], 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTab', on 'Infragistics.Win.Design.SubObjectCodeDomSerializer`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
```

With the stack trace:

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, Int32 numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[]
```

this is in visual studio.

Other errors in the same project when loading the designer are :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

at Infragistics.Win.Misc.Design.UltraPanelDesigner.VerifyClientAreaDesigner()
at Infragistics.Win.Misc.Design.UltraPanelDesigner.Initialize(IComponent component)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)
```

No other designer is showing anything sensible, they either throw one of the above errors or show me small empty designer screen.

I already tried deleting the bin/obj and build a clean version but that didn't, elsewhere on the internet I found that maybe something about conflicting infragistis versions might be part of the problem. But this suggested uninstalling them in the assembly however this seems to assume that there are multiple infragistic versions in the assembly while there was only a s single file there, suggesting it was heavily outdated.

Comment: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/33549.aspx

Comment: I already tried deleting the bin and obj folders.